# sql/access - insert where X doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ms-access, insert-into

First of all,  please be patient I have no database experience and have been tasked with some data entry in access and it is extremely tedious so I have started coding buttons to make my life easier.

I want to insert a row in to FINLDATA MODELS with the FINLDATA_ID and MODEL from the form (F_EDIT_ENTRIES_MODEL_SUB) where the MODEL doesn't exist.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leyMB.png)

[FINLDATA - what populates top part of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSQFQ.png)

[FINLDATA MODELS - populates sub form (where times are assigned)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypTYa.png)

[T_MODEL_LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8jjM.png)

For each OPTION we assign BASE TIMES for current MODELS. Traditionally the person before me copy and pasted down the times in the form (ridiculous). I coded a button to update times to ALL models however this doesn't work if the model has no previous entry for that ID. The form has a list of all models that are current found in T_MODEL_LIST. There are many instances of models having no time attached for a process as there is no record in FINLDATA MODELS

Each process for a given option has a unique FINLDATA_ID, this FINLDATA_ID is the same for all models. FINLDATA MODELS is where the times are that we are updating. Each record has it's own unique FINLDATA_MODEL_ID for each model (See T_MODEL_LIST). The FINLDATA_MODEL_ID is just a number that counts up, e.g. if I were to add a time on the form to a model that previously had no time for that process it would be the total number of records in FINLDATA MODELS +1.

I want to code another button that adds a record to FINLDATA MODELS for each model without time.

The logic would be something like:

INSERT in to FINLDATA MODELS
FINLDATA ID from the FORM (Me.FINLDATA_ID.Value) & MODEL from T_MODEL_LIST where it's not already present in FINLDATA MODELS

E.g. For specific FINLDATA_ID, If MODEL from T_MODEL_LIST doesn't exist in FINLDATA MODELS. INSERT in to FINLDATA MODELS (FINLDATA_ID, MODELS THAT DON'T HAVE RECORDS)

Hope this clears things up. The sub form lists all the models on the left, this is populated by T_MODEL_LIST if that helps.

SQL for query that populates model list in sub form

SELECT T_MODELS_LIST.MODEL AS MASTER_MODEL, T_MODELS_LIST.MODEL_NAME, models.FINLDATA_MODEL_ID, models.FINLDATA_ID, models.MODEL, models.[BASE TIME], models.VERIFICATION, models.COMMENTS, models.[ESTABLISHMENT TIME], models.STATION

FROM T_MODELS_LIST LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [FINLDATA MODELS] WHERE FINLDATA_ID = Forms![F_EDIT_ENTRIES]![FINLDATA_ID])  AS models ON T_MODELS_LIST.MODEL = models.MODEL

WHERE (((T_MODELS_LIST.REMOVED)=No))
ORDER BY T_MODELS_LIST.MODEL;

Thanks all.

Comment: You can't combine an `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` with a `WHERE` clause. `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` inserts just a single row. Sounds like you want an `UPDATE` query or an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` instead, but with your current description, I'm not 100% sure what you want. Can you add sample data for both tables, an input in that form, and the expected output based on that input?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth updated, hopefully clears things up a bit.

Comment: Please read the edit help re code block format. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [DCount](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dcount-function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3), a domain aggregate, to count records in *models* table and decide to run append or update queries according to the count result. Also, consider using parameterized queries with [QueryDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) with prepared queries saved in advance especially since you receive user input.

**SQL** *(save below as stored queries)*

UPDATE

```
PARAMETERS [BaseTimeParam] Long, [IDParam] Long; 
UPDATE [FINLDATA MODELS]
SET [BASE TIME] = [BaseTimeParam] _
WHERE [FINLDATA MODELS].FINLDATA_ID = [IDParam]
```

APPEND

```
PARAMETERS [IDParam] Long, [ModelParam] Long, [BaseTimeParam] Long; 
INSERT INTO [FINLDATA MODELS] (FINLDATA_ID, MODEL, [BASE TIME])
VALUES ([IDParam], [ModelParam], [BaseTimeParam]);
```

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub btnCopyTimes_Click() 
   ' Define variables
   Dim EnteredValue As Double, CheckCount As Long
   Dim IDToUpdate As String
   Dim qdef As QueryDef

   ' Grab ID
   IDToUpdate = Me.FINLDATA_ID.Value

   ' Prompt for new base time for ALL models
    EnteredValue = InputBox("Enter New Base Time for ALL models")

   CheckCount = DCount("*", "T_MODELS_LIST", _
                       "MODEL = " & Me.FINLDATA_MODEL_ID)

   If CheckCount >= 1 Then
       ' RUN UPDATE
       Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myUpdateQuery")

       qdef![BaseTimeParam] = EnteredValue        ' BIND PARAMETERS
       qdef![IDParam] = IDToUpdate 

       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError                 ' EXECUTE ACTION
   Else 
       ' RUN APPEND
       Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myAppendQuery")

       qdef![IDParam] = IDToUpdate                ' BIND PARAMETERS
       qdef![ModelParam] = Me.FINLDATA_MODEL_ID           
       qdef![BaseTimeParam] = EnteredValue

       qdef.Execute dbFailOnError                 ' EXECUTE ACTION
   End If

   Set qdef = Nothing

   ' Refresh the form display
   Me.F_EDIT_ENTRIES_MODEL_SUB.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a good idea as the model list will always have a set number of models. I will give it a go at work and see how I go! Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
' Define variables
Dim IDToUpdate As String
Dim m_strSQL As String

' Grab ID
IDToUpdate = Me.FINLDATA_ID.Value

' INSERT ID and missing model model numbers - WORKS, doesn't skip 'Removed' models
m_strSQL = "INSERT INTO [FINLDATA MODELS] (FINLDATA_ID, MODEL)" & _
            "SELECT '" & IDToUpdate & "', T_MODELS_LIST.MODEL FROM T_MODELS_LIST WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT MODEL FROM [FINLDATA MODELS] WHERE [FINLDATA MODELS].MODEL = T_MODELS_LIST.MODEL)"

RunSQL m_strSQL

' Refresh the form display
Me.F_EDIT_ENTRIES_MODEL_SUB.Form.Requery
```

This is how I ended up getting it working, thank you all!